# Ubuntumate 15.10 cannot login

Tags: login, 15.10, ubuntu-mate

I use mini.iso and install "ubuntu-mate-desktop" only and when reboot, I cannot login the window.

When pressing Ctrl Alt F1, I can log in the command prompt with the account and password I coded during installation. An error message "Failed to start session" appeared with red boundary appeared just on the dialog box below the password entry field.

How to solve this problem?